# Which variables should be private and/or firstprivate when using openMP to parallelize code, and when is that appropriate?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

My task is to parallelize this function and make it faster than the sequential run time, but the #pragma omp parallel for statements I've attempted do not seem to have a substantial effect.

The sequential version of this code is essentially identical, save for the #pragma statements. I realize the code is very poorly written, it's part of the assignment, the goal of which is to achieve an 8x speed-up. The linux machine the code is to run on is an 8-core system with hyperthreading.

The methodology for testing run time is by the output of these lines of code:

```
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
    work_it_par(original, new);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &finish);
```

similar code calls the sequential version of the same function, and then the speed-up is calculated by sequential time/parallel time. However, my results seem to be highly inconsistent and I cannot seem to parallelize beyond 1.5.

```
void work_it_par(long *old, long *new) {
    int i, j, k;
    int u, v, w;
    long compute_it;
    long aggregate=1.0;
    long weNeedTheFunc = we_need_the_func();
    long gimmieTheFunc = gimmie_the_func();
    int marker = DIM-1;
    #pragma omp parallel for private(i, j, k, compute_it)
    for (i=1; i<marker; i++) {
        for (j=1; j<marker; j++) {
            for (k=1; k<marker; k++) {
                compute_it = old[i*DIM*DIM+j*DIM+k] * weNeedTheFunc;
                aggregate+= compute_it / gimmieTheFunc;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("AGGR:%ld\n",aggregate);
//#pragma omp parallel for private(i, j, u, v)
    for (i=1; i<marker; i++) {
#pragma omp parallel for private(k)
    for (j=1; j<marker; j++) {
        for (k=1; k<marker; k++){
            new[i*DIM*DIM+j*DIM+k]=0;
            for (u=-1; u<=1; u++) {
                for (v=-1; v<=1; v++) {
                    for (w=-1; w<=1; w++) {
                        new[i*DIM*DIM+j*DIM+k]+=old[(i+u)*DIM*DIM+(j+v)*DIM+(k+w)];
                    }
                }
            }
        new[i*DIM*DIM+j*DIM+k]/=27;
      }
    }
  }
#pragma omp parallel for private(i, j)
    for (i=1; i<marker; i++) {
//#pragma omp parallel for private(k)
        for (j=1; j<marker; j++) {
            for (k=1; k<marker; k++) {
                u=(new[i*DIM*DIM+j*DIM+k]/100);
                if (u<=0) u=0;
                if (u>=9) u=9;
                histogrammy[u]++;
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: To sum on `agregate` you need an openmp reduction. `u` must be private in third block. In third block, there is problem in the management of histogrammy. Must also be done with a reduction or local variable. Here are some obvious problems in your code.

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, your code is wrong in *many* places. I counted 7 race conditions on a first glance.

I suggest to use the following general rules:

1. Declare variables **as local as possible**. This is easier to get right than trying to figure out which variable needs to be private. It can also help to declare variables as const to see that they can safely be shared.
2. If you sum up a variable in a parallel loop, use a reduction clause.

Applying these principles to the first loop looks like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:aggregate)
for (int i=1; i<marker; i++) {
    for (int j=1; j<marker; j++) {
        for (int k=1; k<marker; k++) {
            long compute_it = old[i*DIM*DIM+j*DIM+k] * weNeedTheFunc;
            aggregate+= compute_it / gimmieTheFunc;
        }
    }
}
```

3. For the histogram, you can also use `reduction(+:histogrammy[:10])` since OpenMP 4.5, or `#pragma omp atomic update` before the increment operation. Which one is better depends on the size - array reduction has a per-thread memory cost, `atomic` update has a contention penalty.
4. Typically, parallelize the outermost loop where it is safe to do so. For nested loops, it can be beneficial to apply a `collapse` clause, which includes multiple loops in the worksharing. Whether that is helps, depends on the number of threads, loop size, and balance. Typically it doesn't hurt.

e.g.

```
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(3)
for (int i=1; i < marker; i++) {
    for (int j=1; j < marker; j++) {
        for (int k=1; k < marker; k++) {
```

If you are done with making sure the code is correct and you want to look at performance please consider the following: Use performance analysis tools that know OpenMP / threads. If you want to discuss actual performance on StackOverflow, you must

1. Include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - including how you build it
2. Describe your specific performance measurement methodology
3. Include your specific performance measurement results
4. Describe your system (CPU, compiler versions)

Answer (score 0):

In general, you must be careful and consider making a variable private when there is an assignment on the var. Otherwise, there is risk of races between threads that will lead to randomly incorrect behavior.

This happens in several situations in your code.
compute_it = ... (already a private var)
agregate+= ... (special case that require a reduction)
u = ... (should be private)
histogram[u]+= ... (again a reduction problem)

Assignments to array elements can also be a problem, but it depends on the indexes. If indexes are thread dependent and different in every thread, then it is generally correct, except for false sharing situations. This is what happens in most you assignments to arrays. For instance for `new[i*DIM*DIM+j*DIM+k]=...`, all threads will have a different i (thanks to the parallel for), different parts of the array will be concerned and there is not specific parallel problem.
For the assignment to `histogrammy[u]`, the situation is different, as u is data dependent and can be identical in different threads. It can be managed with a reduction in newer omp versions, but otherwise a local accumulation must be done and at the end of the thread the global array updated in a properly protected region.

Here is a reworked version of your code (untested, as you did not deliver a working example). I also added some comments and modifications unrelated to parallelization. Check the comment with a triple ///

```
void work_it_par(long *old, long *new) {
    int i, j, k;
    int u, v, w;
    long compute_it;
    long aggregate=1.0;    //// really?
                           //// I am really surprised that you use a long. 
                           ////   A double seems more appropriate
    long weNeedTheFunc = we_need_the_func();
    long gimmieTheFunc = gimmie_the_func();
    int marker = DIM-1; 
///    #pragma omp parallel for private(i, j, k, compute_it)
#   pragma omp parallel for private(i, j, k, compute_it) reduction(+:aggregate) 
                    /// introduced a reduction on aggregate
    for (i=1; i<marker; i++) {
        for (j=1; j<marker; j++) {
            for (k=1; k<marker; k++) {
                compute_it = old[i*DIM*DIM+j*DIM+k] * weNeedTheFunc;  
                /// aggregate+= compute_it / gimmieTheFunc; /// race on shared var aggregate 
                                                            /// solved by the reduction
                aggregate += compute_it ; /// Unrelated to parallel processing, 
                                          /// but do not do a division in your loop
                                          /// divisions are *expensive* and
                                          /// denominator is always the same
            }
        }
    }
    aggregate /= gimmieTheFunc ; /// now we do the division, but just once
    printf("AGGR:%ld\n",aggregate);
//#pragma omp parallel for private(i, j, u, v)
    for (i=1; i<marker; i++) {
#pragma omp parallel for private(k)
    for (j=1; j<marker; j++) {
        for (k=1; k<marker; k++){
            new[i*DIM*DIM+j*DIM+k]=0;
            for (u=-1; u<=1; u++) {  
                for (v=-1; v<=1; v++) {
                    for (w=-1; w<=1; w++) {
                        new[i*DIM*DIM+j*DIM+k]+=old[(i+u)*DIM*DIM+(j+v)*DIM+(k+w)];
                    }
                }
            }
        new[i*DIM*DIM+j*DIM+k]/=27;
      }
    }
  }
///#pragma omp parallel for private(i, j)
#pragma omp parallel private(i, j, u)  /// parallel region
  {
    int private_histogrammy[10]; /// used to accumulate in the threads
    for (int ii=0; ii<10; ii++) private_histogrammy[ii]=0;
#   pragma omp for             /// a parallel for loop in the parallel region
    for (i=1; i<marker; i++) {
        for (j=1; j<marker; j++) {
            for (k=1; k<marker; k++) {
///                u=(new[i*DIM*DIM+j*DIM+k]/100);
                u=(new[i*DIM*DIM+j*DIM+k]); /// to reduce number of divisions
///                if (u<=0) u=0;
///                if (u>=9) u=9;
///                histogrammy[u]++;
                if (u<=0) private_histogrammy[0]++;
                else if (u>=900) private_histogrammy[9]++;
                else private_histogrammy[u/100]++;
             }
         }
    }
    /// all is done update the global histogrammy
#   pragma omp critical
    /// update the shared array
    /// probably faster with a critical section that updates globally
    /// the (small) array than using atomic on array elements
    /// but alternatives may be tested
    for (int uu=0; uu<10; uu++) histogrammy[uu] += private_histogrammy[uu];
  }  /// end of parallel region
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved 12x clock times with the following answer. You can get even finer optimization by converting all three large loops into one single 3-tiered loop and setting up parallel omp pragmas inside the loop to control the flow.

```html
void work_it_par(long *old, long *new) {
    int i, j, k;
    int i1,j1,k1;
    int u, v, w;
    long compute_it;
    long aggregate=1.0;
    int N = DIM-1;
    int gimme = gimmie_the_func();
    int need = we_need_the_func();
#   pragma omp parallel for private(i, j, k, compute_it) reduction(+:aggregate)     //reduce this part
    for (i=1; i<N; i++)
    {
        for (j=1; j<N; j++)
        {
            for (k=1; k<N; k++)
            {
                compute_it = old[i*DIM*DIM+j*DIM+k] * need;    ///removed the multiplications and divisions
                aggregate += compute_it / gimme;
            }
        }
    }
    //aggregate *= need;
    //aggregate /= gimme;
    
    printf("AGGR:%ld\n",aggregate);
    int increment = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for private(i,j,k,i1,j1,k1) reduction(+:increment)
    for (i=1; i<N; i+=30)
    {
        for (j=1; j<N; j+=30)
        {
            for (k=1; k<N; k+=30)
            {
                for (i1 =i ; i1 < i+30 && i1 < N ; i1++)
                {
                    for (j1 =i ; j1 < i+30 && j1 < N; j1++)
                    {
                        for (k1 =i ; k1 < i+30 && k1 < N ; k1++)
                        {
                            int index = i1*DIM*DIM+j1*DIM+k1;

                            int D = DIM;
                            int DSq = DIM*DIM;
                            increment = 0;
                            increment+=old[index-DSq-D-1];      //-1,-1
                            increment+=old[index-DSq-D];
                            increment+=old[index-DSq-D+1];
                            increment+=old[index-DSq-1];        //-1,0,
                            increment+=old[index-DSq];
                            increment+=old[index-DSq+1];
                            increment+=old[index-DSq+D-1];      //-1,1
                            increment+=old[index-DSq+D];
                            increment+=old[index-DSq+D+1];
                            increment+=old[index-D-1];          //0,-1
                            increment+=old[index-D];
                            increment+=old[index-D+1];
                            increment+=old[index-1];            //0,0
                            increment+=old[index];
                            increment+=old[index+1];
                            increment+=old[index+D-1];          //0,1
                            increment+=old[index+D];
                            increment+=old[index+D+1];
                            increment+=old[index+DSq-D-1];      //1,-1
                            increment+=old[index+DSq-D];
                            increment+=old[index+DSq-D+1];
                            increment+=old[index+DSq-1];        //1,0
                            increment+=old[index+DSq];
                            increment+=old[index+DSq+1];
                            increment+=old[index+DSq+D-1];      //1,1
                            increment+=old[index+DSq+D];
                            increment+=old[index+DSq+D+1];
                            
                            new[index] = increment;
                            
                            new[index]/=27;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int count0,count1,count2,count3,count4,count5,count6,count7,count8,count9 = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for private (i,j,k) reduction(+:count0,count1,count2,count3,count4,count5,count6,count7,count8,count9)
    for (i=1; i<N; i++)
    {
        for (j=1; j<N; j++)
        {
            for (k=1; k<N; k++)
            {
                u=(new[i*DIM*DIM+j*DIM+k]/100);
                if (u<=0) u = 0;
                if (u>=9) u = 9;
                switch (u) {
                    case 0:
                        count0 ++;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        count1 ++;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        count2 ++;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        count3 ++;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        count4 ++;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        count5 ++;
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        count6 ++;
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        count7 ++;
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        count8 ++;
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        count9 ++;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    histogrammy[0] += count0;
    histogrammy[1] += count1;
    histogrammy[2] += count2;
    histogrammy[3] += count3;
    histogrammy[4] += count4;
    histogrammy[5] += count5;
    histogrammy[6] += count6;
    histogrammy[7] += count7;
    histogrammy[8] += count8;
    histogrammy[9] += count9;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was so helpful. I think what I was missing was the addition of the loop tiling. That made such a difference in addition to the #pragmas.

Comment: Just don't forget to mark this as the answer and upvote :).